# How do you apply a clipping mask to multiple layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I have 20 multiple images in different layers withon a Photoshop file.  I want to apply one clipping mask for all the layers.  I grouped all layers and tried but the clipping mask option is disabled.  How can I apply one clipping mask to multiple layers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Highlight all the layers and choose "Convert To Smart Object" from the **Layer Panel Menu**.

Apply your clipping mask to the resulting Smart Object.

---

To address the comment below:

If you wish to retain existing smart objects, then merely **Group** all the layers you wish to mask in the Layers Panel, and apply the mask to the **Group**.

[image]

Comment: Your solution works like a charm but there's a problem if one of the highlighted layers is already a Smart Object. I have multiple instances of this object in the drawing. When I do as you say, the selected instance of the object is copied as a __new__ smart object. I'd like it to stay __the same__ Smart Object as before. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop CS6, select all the layers you wish to be clipped, click on the Layers panel flyout menu and choose "Create Clipping Mask".

Make sure the masking layer is immediately below the bottom-most layer to be masked (and not selected).

Alternatively, if Layer Masks are acceptable, you can group the Layers and add a Layer Mask to the layer group.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder and place all your layers inside.  Then mask the folder itself.  Every layer inside the folder will be masked by the folder and not the individual layer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: These are the layers that need to be clipped]

Select multiple layers by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

[image: Select the layers you want to clip]

Now *Right-click* on the selected layer stack that you wish to clip and press the <kbd>Create clipping mask</kbd> button.

[image: Right-click on them and press "Create Clipping Mask]

It should clip all selected layers in one go.

[image: Done!]

(Update) In Photoshop 22.4.3, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> after having selected the layers.