# Blend mode for adjusting opacity

Tags: gimp, transparency, blend-modes

I have created a new layer *X* which I wish to apply to the lower layers with a blend mode such that the resulting image takes its alpha channel from layer *X* but all other channels from the lower layers. In this way, the layer *X* only defines the opacity of the resulting image. Does such a blend mode exist, and if so, what is it called? Does it exist in the GIMP?

Comment: I think this might be what you're after: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54781/gimp-how-to-apply-a-mask-to-multiple-layers -- sounds like a huge pain not being able to mask a layer group, but then it is free software

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that question is slightly different. That question is about applying an existing mask to a number of layers (not about creating that mask), and this question is about creating a mask _from_ an actual image or layer... I think.

Comment: @Ryan In Gimp 2.10, you can add layer masks to layer groups