# GIMP: How to change opacity of multiple layers?

Tags: gimp, layers, transparency

How do I change the opacity of multiple layers simultaneously in GIMP?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't do it that way, as it's not possible to select multiple layers in GIMP currently. However, you can put the layers in a layer group, and then change the opacity of the group.

Comment: Like [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/121921/67201)